# R apache errors

Tags: apache, r, rapache

I did search and couldn't find an answer. If anybody could glance at this and shares the what I am doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it:

This is what I have in my `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/R> 
    SetHandler r-script 
    RHandler sys.source 
</Directory>
```

This is the content of `test.R`, very simple:

```
<% 
x<-1:10000 
t=plot(x) 
print(t) 
%>
```

I get an Internal Server error when I enter the URL, `http://localhost/R/test.R`. Apache log says this:

> ```
> Traceback: 
> 2: parse(n = -1, file = file) 
> 1: sys.source(file = "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/R/test.R", envir = .rAenv)
> ```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't cross-post between SO and the mailing list. Pick one, and if you don't get a good answer after several days, try the other.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in [Section 3.6.6](http://rapache.net/manual.html#Configuring_rapache) of the online [Rapache manual](http://rapache.net/manual.html), "Any file under /var/www/R-files [/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/R in your example] is passed through the function sys.source."

`<%` and `%>` are not valid R code, so `sys.source` pukes.

Comment: after taking out those tags, still the same problem.